# What is grammitcally correct when trying ot schedule an appointment

Tags: phrases

.. Any ‘ol way.. just let me know when you are/will be free upon your return.

Comment: If you are being formal, "will be" is appropriate. Informally, "are" will do.

Comment: Combining "any ol' way" and "upon your return" in the same sentence is an amazing clash of style.